# compare c# instance objects in f#

Tags: c#, f#, xunit

I am new to F#, and trying to learn F# by writing unit tests for C# library.

Below is sample C# code -

```
 public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class UserSelector
{
    public User SelectUser()
    {
        return new User() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Public" };
    }
}
```

In F# I am writing Unit tests with xunit -

Below is sample F# Code -

```
module UserSelectorTests =

[<Fact>]
let ``SelectUser Tests``() =
    let actual = (new UserSelector()).SelectUser()
    let expected = new User(FirstName = "John", LastName = "Public")
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual)
```

Even though actual and expected are same the test fails.

Any ideas on how to compare objects in F#?

Comment: In c# they would also be different. You are comparing references to object instances. You created two instances. Those instances are not equal. Either your User class has to implement Equals or you have to compare state, aka FirstName and LastName for actual and expected.

Comment: Thanks,  Just after posting this question I stumbled upon similar question asked in c#. Thank you rene!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rene mentioned in the comments, User class needed to implement Equals.